# How to expose field collection's items id or UUID to the front end?

Tags: 8, debugging, entities

I'm working with the Drupal 8 field collections and currently have setup a custom collection that is an editable widget on the edit pages. I'm trying to target these collection items via their unique item_id or uuid, but when inspecting the html code. I can't seem to find any source that shows these unique identifiers.

Below is the image of the database results of the field collection id's, just to show that they do indeed exist.

Since this is a Drupal 8 module, I tried to trace some of the elements that are being rendered to the front end. For instance the REMOVE button. I'm able to find it in the following file:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/field_collection/tree/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/FieldCollectionEmbedWidget.php

But from here on, I'm quite unsure of how to even expose the **item_id** or **uuid**. I tried to dpm() a bunch of arrays and variables, but I can't seem to find anything that matches what is in the database.

How would one go about finding the **item_id** or **uuid** in the following code for Drupal 8 Field collection?

[image]

[image]

And another screenshot of not being able to find these unique identifiers.

[image]